# What do the Amish believe with respect to Creationism?

Tags: creation, young-earth-creation, amish

I realize there are numerous denominations of the Amish, but I'm wondering whether any or all of them believe in the literal, six-day creation and a six-thousand-year-old earth. I've looked in many places but haven't found anything definitive.

Comment: Amish craftsmen are helping AnswersInGenesis build the full-scale model of Noah's ark. This indicates a certain receptiveness to the traditional interpretation of Genesis.

Comment: Found a good Amish site: http://groups.etown.edu                            From the site: "The Amish support education in a broad sense, but they think that, beyond elementary school, vocational training is sufficient for success in their society." Seems to indicate (?) that evolution isn't something they focus on.

Comment: I can't figure why there aren't many Amish contributors here

Comment: @andrew because we don't have a good implementation of [RFC 1149](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers).

Comment: Most Amish craftsmen I have met would help you build a data hub for your driverless cars if you asked. They don't usually refuse work because the end product isn't something they would use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm Amish -- sort of.* You are correct that there is a lot of variation within the Amish tradition (and even more if you include Mennonites, another branch of the Anabaptist heritage), so I can't speak for all. However, I think I'd be fairly safe to say that many, if not most, of us believe generally in a young earth and a literal six-day creation.

Historically, the issue was not a major focus, especially since Amish and conservative Mennonite involvement in higher education was (and still is) fairly limited. However, even the Amish and Mennonites have been influenced by fundamentalism, with its insistence on Biblical literalism and rejection of "modernism." Organizations like Answers in Genesis have had a large influence on many conservative Anabaptists.

...

*
I'm a member of the Beachy Amish-Mennonites, an offshoot of the Amish.  There is quite a bit of variation within the "Beachys" as well, but we all have cars and electricity and phones. Many of us utilize the internet regularly and live fairly normal American lives, while still maintaining some degree of distinctive dress and lifestyle. (The [Mennonite Encyclopedia Online](http://www.gameo.org/index.php?title=Beachy_Amish_Mennonite_Fellowship) has more about our history and name, while [this very unofficial but fairly informative site](http://www.beachyam.org) has some pictures, FAQs, and more.

Comment: After re-reading your answer a couple of times, I notice you said "young" earth, rather than the 6000-year-old earth. Is that to suggest that you don't believe the 6k years? Or am I reading too much? If you believe something else, could you comment on the variety of beliefs among your fellows, with respect to the age of the earth?

Comment: My interaction with old order Amish in Pennsylvania would agree with this. @GreatBigBore even among YEC, young earth creationism, there is debate whether that means 6000, or If it is even up to 30,000 years. I think it would be difficult to fairly answer that. BUT, I think its likely that without much thought they would default to the ~6000 years just as many YEC church-going laymen would, without any real personal research. "We don't really get into that" is a common answer I get when asking Amish detailed questions about things like this or intermediate state.

Comment: My hunch would be much like what @Joshua said, i.e. ~6000 years would be the prevailing belief. I was raised with this understanding, and most of my Amish/Mennonite acquaintances are of this persuasion too. Compared to many of them, I am probably a bit more open to other interpretations -- and I know of a few others like me who are willing to at least consider other models. But generally speaking, I think many/most of us would default to ~6000 years.

Answer (score 2):

Most Amish believe in a young earth and a six day creation. I am closely associated with the Amish and I speak from experience.  I have yet to meet an Amish person who does not conform to this belief system. Furthermore, the Amish are involved in ministries such as Answers In Genesis.